# Using WDK to make a driver for a bluetooth gamepad

Tags: c, bluetooth, driver, wdk, gamepad

I am trying to make a Windows driver for a bluetooth gamepad, I know exactly what data the gamepad sends via bluetooth, but I have no clue where to start with this project, I have searched far and wide for more information about how to recieve data through bluetooth with WDK, but I have yet to a good source of documentation or a good example. Everything has to be coded in C, I have already setup the basic driver and tested it on the device, all i need now is functionality.

So my questions are:

1. How do you connect to the right bluetooth device
2. How do you send/recieve bluetooth data using WDK
3. How do you emulate a HID gamepad device after parsing the bluetooth data

Any links to documentation, examples or possibly books would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can start from this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/samples/bluetooth-driver-samples

Comment: I have looked at all of the samples, but it doesn't really give me a general idea of how it actually works, I could just copy/paste, but I wouldn't learn anything from that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bluetooth/

Comment: BTW, if your controller is classic Bluetooth device then it implements Bluetooth HID profile. Bluetooth HID is L2CAP based profile so start from L2CAP driver sample. If your controller is BLE then start from BLE profile driver sample.

Comment: The controller is a BLE device, should I then use the _serialhcibus_ example, if so then i have already tried to understand it, but i cant really seem to get the hang of what is going on in each individual file and function.

Comment: It looks they removed this from internal. There was a Heat Rate Profile driver sample in Win 8.1 WDK. Unfortunately I could not find it fast in google, but that should be a start point. AFAIR Win 10 should support GATT HID devices. But my opinion is that it is better to stay with user-mode in such case.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to find a Heart Rate Profile driver

Comment: Here I found more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45773666/developing-an-hid-input-device-driver-for-a-ble-gatt-device-on-windows-10

Comment: It looks you can stay in user-mode using UMDF HID (see the answer by the link I posted above)

Comment: My driver is currently a KMDF driver, is it best to switch to UMDF or should i just stick with KMDF?

Comment: For Win 10 UMDF looks better but this is just my opinion.

Comment: So from the links you sent me, I have a better understanding of how to setup a HID driver, but how would I connect to a bluetooth device and start sending/receiving data.

Comment: In user mode or in kernel mode?

Comment: In kernel mode.

Comment: In kernel mode is only way is to find old WDK from Win 8.1 and to hope that it will ork on Win 10 because win 10 WDK does not include any LE drivers demo (at least I could not find it).

Comment: It's this sample you are referring to right?
https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/tree/master/Official%20Windows%20Driver%20Kit%20Sample/Windows%20Driver%20Kit%20(WDK)%208.0%20Samples/%5BC%2B%2B%5D-Windows%20Driver%20Kit%20(WDK)%208.0%20Samples/C%2B%2B/WDK%208.0%20Samples/Bluetooth%20Low%20Energy%20(LE)%20Generic%20Attribute%20(GATT)%20Profile%20Drivers

Comment: Yes, that is the one I meant.

Comment: I will try and look into it.